# Finding an upper bound for solution of $Ax=b$

Tags: linear-algebra

Is there any upper bound on $x$ in $ Ax=b $ using some features of $A$, for example $ \min(\lambda_i) $ or $ \max(\lambda_i) $ eigenvalues of $A$ ?

I've tried to find something like
$$ \Vert x\Vert  \le f(\lambda_i)\Vert b\Vert $$
That is

$$ \Vert x\Vert \le \Vert A^{-1}\Vert_{op}\Vert b\Vert$$

But I couldn't find any relation between $\Vert A^{-1}\Vert_{op}$ and the $\lambda_i$

Comment: Besides I've searched a lot and no one worked on an upper bound on x, for linear equation Ax=b, that's amazing.

Comment: See the [condition number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condition_number) of a matrix

Comment: What do you mean by "nobody worked on an upper bound on $x$"? The norm of $x$ is bounded simply by $\|A^{-1}\|\|b\|$, what else would you expect? Anyway, if $A$ is normal, you can replace $\|A^{-1}\|$ by $(\min_i|\lambda_i|)^{-1}$ provided $\|\cdot\|$ is the spectral norm. Otherwise, there's no such bound exclusively in terms of the eigenvalues.